# How to add a layout to a View before the View is used in the activity with setContentView(View)?

Tags: android

How to add a layout to a View before the View is used in the activity with setContentView(View)?
I am trying to add LinearLayout to a Layout View programatticaly how do I accomplish this?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        LinearLayout bar = new LinearLayout(context);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens? Any Exceptions? Why don't you just add it after setContentView()?

Comment: You can inflate your layout before and use setContentView(View view) method to set your layout to activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);` first and them you work with it and add other views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. In onCreate do

```
ViewGroup view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
view.add(YOUR_VIEW);
setContentView(view);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add layout after setContentView programmatically. But you Can Include a layout in your view via XML if you need it before setContentView .